# Temp store an object in java

Tags: java, object, store, move

Is it possible to temporarily store an object?

What I intend doing is to temporarily store an object, remove the original then put the temp object elsewhere?

So this gives the impression I'm "moving" the object effectively.

Many thanks,

Comment: It might be that is late here, but I don't understand it. Do you mind rephrasing it somewhat?

Comment: Define "moving". Define "elsewhere".

Comment: Basically, I have an array list of teams and an array list players. I want to create a temp copy of the player, remove it from that team, then re add the copy to the new team

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you're saying either.  Do you mean you want to use a temporary variable to swap the objects between two other variables?

Comment: Why can't you just add the player to team B and remove it from team A?

Comment: Wouldnt you need a copy of all the parameters of the player to add it to team b though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Player tempPlayer = new Player();
tempPlayer.setValueA() = originalPlayer.getValueA();
// copy all values this way
team.remove(originalPlayer);
// more code
team2.add(tempPlayer);
```

Does this answer look ok?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two lists:

```
ArrayList<Player> team1, team2;
```

And you want to move a player from `team1` to `team2`.

---

It appears you want to add a copy, not the original, to the new team.  Changed slightly:

There are two ways to do that, the short way and the clear way.  Either way, you'll need the index of the player.  You probably want the clear way:

```
Player oldPlayer = team1.remove(playerIndex);
Player newPlayer = oldPlayer.clone();
team2.add(newPlayer);
```

For reference, the faster way is:

```
team2.add(team1.remove(playerIndex).clone());
```

Although this does require you to implement the `Cloneable` interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help but what I have is an array list for teams, and an array list for players.

Comment: So then where are you moving the player from and to?  Is the player's team a field in the `Player` object?

Comment: Iterate through the each team and add a player that way so each team has its unique players. So theoretically I think I need to some how iterate through, copy the player, remove it from that team. Then iterate again until the desired team is found then re add the copy of the player?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the player you intend to move from team A to team B is the *k*-th player in team A (counting from 0, i.e. for the first player k=0, etc):

```
ArrayList<Player> teamA = ... // contains player p
ArrayList<Player> teamB = ... // does not contain player p
Player p = teamA.get(k);
teamB.add(p);
teamA.remove(p); // Note: you can also use index
```

There may be other methods of getting access to the player you intend to move depending on the context. See [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more available methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but for others that find themselves here:

The most practical thing to use in this case are [Stacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) or [Deques](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).
These allow you to add objects to a stack and then pop them which removes them.
Stacks do things pretty much the same way Deques do, but Deques are actually a bit more flexible and preferred over Stacks in coding.